# Cumulative sum by category with DAX (Without Date dimension)

Tags: dax, cumulative-sum

This is the input data (Let's suppose that I have 14 different products), I need to calculate with DAX, cumulative Total products by Status

| ProductID | Days Since LastPurchase | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 307255900 | 76 | 60 - 180 days |
| 525220000 | 59 | 30 - 60 days |
| 209500000 | 20 | < 30 days |
| 312969600 | 151 | 60 - 180 days |
| 249300000 | 52 | 30 - 60 days |
| 210100000 | 52 | 30 - 60 days |
| 304851400 | 150 | 60 - 180 days |
| 304851600 | 150 | 60 - 180 days |
| 314152700 | 367 | > 180 days |
| 405300000 | 90 | 60 - 180 days |
| 314692300 | 90 | 60 - 180 days |
| 314692400 | 53 | 30 - 60 days |
| 524270000 | 213 | > 180 days |
| 524280000 | 213 | > 180 days |

Desire ouput:

| Status | Cumulative Count |
| --- | --- |
| < 30 days | 1 |
| > 180 days | 4 |
| 30 - 60 days | 8 |
| 60 - 180 days | 14 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's trivial: Just take the build in `Quick measure` "Running total", see screenshot.

[image]

The resulting table will look like this:

[image]

However, when you think about it, from a data point of view a sort order like the following makes more sense than ordering "status" by alphabet,

[image]

and finally you can take it straight away without any crude categorization

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, I've never used before Quick Measures :)